# Unable to connect to network share

Tags: networking, file-sharing, server-message-block

On our company network there are a number of clients that are having problems connecting to the company file server (Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise x86).
The share are mapped to a drive letter on the client. The drives are showing up with a red X and can't be opened.

Most people can access the network shares ok.

I have an idea that the workstation service is at fault.
The output of net config workstation on a faulty computer is

```
C:\>net config workstation
Computer name                        \\vistacomputer
Full Computer name                   vistacomputer.xxxx.xxxx-xxxxxx.co.uk
User name                            username

Workstation active on 

Software version                     Windows Vista (TM) Business

Workstation domain                   xxxxxx
Workstation Domain DNS Name          xxxxxx.xxxx-xxxxxxxxx.co.uk
Logon domain                         xxxxxx

COM Open Timeout (sec)               0
COM Send Count (byte)                16
COM Send Timeout (msec)              250
The command completed successfully.
```

On a working computer it is

```
C:\>net config workstation
Computer name                        \\vistacomputerthatworks
Full Computer name                   vistacomputerthatworks.xxxx.xxxx-xxxxxx.co.uk
User name                            username

Workstation active on
     NetbiosSmb (000000000000)
     NetBT_Tcpip_{DABE06A7-5BF8-4ADF-B6C4-73EDB8D7971B} (00505694241B)

Software version                     Windows Vista (TM) Business

Workstation domain                   xxxxxx
Workstation Domain DNS Name          xxxxxx.xxxx-xxxxxxxxx.co.uk
Logon domain                         xxxxxx

COM Open Timeout (sec)               0
COM Send Count (byte)                16
COM Send Timeout (msec)              250
The command completed successfully.
```

Looks like the workstation service is disassociating itself from the network connections.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the file server running on?

Comment: @mh file server is running Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise x86

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling Client for Microsoft Networks, reinstalling the network card doesn't associate the workstation properly with the network connection. At a dead end i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved this problem. It's some how related to IPv6. When I disable IPv6 on the problematic systems and then delete all the 6TO4 adapters then the workstation service comes back to life. I deleted all the adapters using devcon.exe from windows support tools. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

OK, identify what's different about the clients that don't work.  Software installed, patch levels, switch ports connected to, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32694961/cant-access-shared-files.aspx) seemed to hint (if you read the replies) that it's antivirus related or irpsize in the registry that's related to the issue you're describing.

Comment: I disabled the McAfee Virusscan Enterprise that is our standard AV but didn't make any difference

Comment: Even after reboot? And the irp size change didn't work either, post reboot? :-/

Answer (score 0):

First Check if the client is able to access other computer's shared folders or not. If not than try following.

Sometimes because of some critical windows process, windows automatically stops following services.

(1) Background Intelligent Transfer Services
(2) Computer Browser
(3) Network Connection

Make Sure this services are running.

Click Start > Run > Type Services.msc   Click Enter to access service console.

click on the service mentioned above. Right Click on it and click start.

Hope this will work for you.